# a bs4 script gives back a empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list with around 50 entries from centers in Germany. These centers are public institutions and are close to the economy. I want to create a list with all the centers _categories

```
Industry sectors:  
Location:  
Contact person:
```

The data - they can be found here on the overview page:
https://www.mittelstand-digital.de/MD/Redaktion/DE/artikel/Mittelstand-4-0/mittelstand-40-unternehmen.html

The idea is to use a parser (scraper) that uses Python and Beautiful Soup and then writes the data into a Calc spreadsheet via Pandas.
So i go like so:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    
    # URL der Webseite
    url = "https://www.mittelstand-digital.de/MD/Redaktion/DE/Artikel/Mittelstand-4-0/mittelstand-40-kompetenzzentren.html"
    
    # Webseiteninhalt abrufen
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Leere Listen für die Daten erstellen
    themen_list = []
    branchen_list = []
    ort_list = []
    ansprechpartner_list = []
    
    # Zentren-Daten extrahieren und den Listen hinzufügen
    for center in soup.find_all('div', class_='linkblock'):
        themen_list.append(center.find('h3').text.strip())
        branchen_list.append(center.find('p', class_='text').text.strip())
        ort_list.append(center.find('span', class_='ort').text.strip())
        ansprechpartner_list.append(center.find('span', class_='ansprechpartner').text.strip())
    
    # Daten in ein Pandas DataFrame umwandeln
    data = {
        'Themen': themen_list,
        'Branchen': branchen_list,
        'Ort': ort_list,
        'Ansprechpartner': ansprechpartner_list
    }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

but this does not work at the moment.  I only get back a enpty list

Comment: If I request the URL in your question, the content does not contain anywhere the class `linkblock`. Try writing out the result of `requests.get` to a file and inspecting the HTML to make sure it looks like you expect.

Comment: good day dear larsk - many thanks for the quick reply. i will check it and digg deeper into all that. Thank you for your great hint!

Comment: note - well i run this in colab - so i have to take care that all the necessary libraries are loaded - i will have a closer look at all that and come back

Comment: many thanks dear @larsks : awesome many  thanks for your hints:  could you plz have a closer look at the other question regarding clutch.co - that i now try to scrape with selenium. - see: question/77856655/getting-results-back-with-selenium-and-python-on-clutch-co-see-some-interestin   - look forward to hear from you there!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you missed scraping the links of all centers first to iterate them one by one and extract your information. Try to avoid the bunch of lists instead use a single one with structured `dict`.

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL der Webseite
url = "https://www.mittelstand-digital.de/MD/Redaktion/DE/Artikel/Mittelstand-4-0/mittelstand-40-kompetenzzentren.html"

# Webseiteninhalt abrufen
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = []

# iterate each center page and extract data
for center in soup.select('.content a.link.ExtBasepage:has(span)'):
    response = requests.get(center.get('href'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    d = dict(e.stripped_strings for e in soup.select('.document-info-item'))
    d.update({'Ansprechpartner':soup.find(class_='card-contactdata').get_text('|',strip= True)})
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
Themen: Branchen:   Ort:    Ansprechpartner
0   Assistenzsysteme, Digitale Bildung, Digita...   Dienstleistungen, Energie, Handwerk und Baue... Denninger Str. 84, 81925 München    © Mittelstand-Digital Zentrum Augsburg|Ansprec...
1   Vernetzte Produktion, Assistenzsysteme, Cl...   Energie, Handwerk und Bauen, Dienstleistungen   Fraunhoferstraße 10, 83626 Valley   © Mittelstand-Digital Zentrum Bau|Ansprechpart...
2   Assistenzsysteme, Digitale Bildung, Künstl...   Dienstleistungen, Handel (Binnenhandel, Gast... Potsdamer Straße 7, 10785 Berlin    © Mittelstand-Digital Zentrum Berlin|Ansprechp...
```

Comment: good day dear HdgeHog - many thanks for the quick reply and the awesome hints.

Comment: good evening dear HedgeHog - many thanks for the reply. _I am very happy. one little thing. These results your code gives back lack a. the full text and b.  the concact data (eg. e-mail) , But besides this is this great. Many thanks for your great approach. Dear HedgeHog - could you plz have a closer look at the other question regarding clutch.co - that i now try to scrape with selenium. - see: question/77856655/getting-results-back-with-selenium-and-python-on-clutch-co-see-some-interestin   - look forward to hear from you there!!